# How do you forward controls to a stackpanel in a custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a custom control which streamlines the look of toolbars across my application. Unfortunately i can't seem to find a way to forward children from my control to the underlying stackpanel. I've tried to solve it by using an ItemsControl, but that does not appear to be working either sadly.

Another approach i took is using OnApplyTemplate in the ToolbarPanel, but that does not seem to be working either.

#### Does anyone know how to get control forwarding working here?

### ToolbarPanel.cs

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(InternalContent))]
public class ToolbarPanel : ContentControl
{
    static ToolbarPanel()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ToolbarPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ToolbarPanel)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InternalContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(InternalContent), typeof(object), typeof(ToolbarPanel), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public object InternalContent
    {
        get { return (object) GetValue(InternalContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InternalContentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

### Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ToolbarPanel}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ToolbarPanel}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding InternalContent}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I don't see `StackPanel`.

Comment: Why don't you derive from ItemsControl?

Comment: @Sinatr Yes. The sample points out that even with a ItemsControl i can't seem to pass through controls assigned to this panel. Doing this with a StackPanel would be the ideal solution to me.

Comment: @Clemens because i don't want the properties of ItemsControl to be inherited. All i want is the behavior of a StackPanel without its properties.

Comment: Why don't you inherit your custom control directly from StackPanel?

Comment: Makes no sense to me. A Toolbar is like a Menu, which also is an ItemsControl. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Clemens didn't look at this from that standpoint tbh. I've got a working solution thanks to your suggestion and combined both attempts which resulted in a working solution. So thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Clemens i managed to come up with an approach that ended up working. Key factors here of why previous attempts failed is because i did not use `ItemsControl` and because i did not set `IsItemsHost` to true. Once i did that, the `StackPanel` did exactly what i was expecting.

ToolbarPanel.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace NetworkMonitor.Framework.Controls
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Items))]
    public class ToolbarPanel : ItemsControl
    {
        static ToolbarPanel()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ToolbarPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ToolbarPanel)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSpacingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ItemsSpacing), typeof(Thickness), typeof(ToolbarPanel), new PropertyMetadata(default(Thickness)));

        public Thickness ItemsSpacing
        {
            get { return (Thickness) GetValue(ItemsSpacingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSpacingProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

PanelExtensions.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace NetworkMonitor.Framework.Controls.Extensions
{
    public class PanelExtensions
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildMarginProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ChildMargin", typeof(Thickness), typeof(PanelExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(), ChildMarginChanged));

        private static void ChildMarginChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is Panel panel)
            {
                panel.Loaded += PanelOnLoaded;
            }
        }

        private static void PanelOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Panel panel)
            {
                panel.Loaded -= PanelOnLoaded;

                var itemsMargin = GetChildMargin(panel);
                var skipLast = GetSkipLastMargin(panel);

                for (int i = 0; i < panel.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (skipLast && i == (panel.Children.Count - 1))
                        break;

                    var child = panel.Children[i];
                    if (child is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
                    {
                        frameworkElement.Margin = itemsMargin;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildren(IncludeDescendants = true)]
        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(Panel))]
        public static void SetChildMargin(DependencyObject element, Thickness value)
        {
            element.SetValue(ChildMarginProperty, value);
        }

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildren(IncludeDescendants = true)]
        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(Panel))]
        public static Thickness GetChildMargin(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (Thickness) element.GetValue(ChildMarginProperty);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SkipLastMarginProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SkipLastMargin", typeof(bool), typeof(PanelExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(true));

        public static void SetSkipLastMargin(DependencyObject element, bool value)
        {
            element.SetValue(SkipLastMarginProperty, value);
        }

        public static bool GetSkipLastMargin(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (bool) element.GetValue(SkipLastMarginProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ToolbarPanel}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSpacing" Value="0,0,8,0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ToolbarPanel}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                IsItemsHost="True"
                                extensions:PanelExtensions.ChildMargin="{TemplateBinding ItemsSpacing}" 
                                extensions:PanelExtensions.SkipLastMargin="True">
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```